# make number (1) different looking than letter (I)

Tags: fonts, letters, number

I am doing a table and using both number 1 and the letter I in the same table. the problem is that they look similar and that creates confusion even for me.

Is there a way to make them look dissimilar somehow?

Here is an example:

```
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{LOO}
\label{backforward}
\begin{tabular}{p{5cm}|p{3cm}|p{3cm}}
 \hline
 %\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Connections} \\
%\hline
Connections & Correlation & p value \\
 \hline
lFP1 $\rightarrow$ lV1 & 0.02 & 0.405\\
lPI $\rightarrow$ lAI & -0.04 & 0.679 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: That is caption setup, please extend your sniplet to a full but minimal example so we can see which documentclass and preamble you are using.

Comment: is this the one you are asking about:      ' \documentclass[BTech]{iitddiss}      \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}'

Answer (score 2):

The distinction between l and 1 depends entirely on the font choice, about which you gave no indication.  You can chose a different style, say italic, or you can change the font of the whole document to choose a font with more distinctive l.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{stix2}
\begin{document}

T1 lFP1  

T2 \textsf{lFP}1 

T3 \textit{lFP}1

M1 $\mathrm{lFP}1$

M2 $\mathsf{lFP}1$

M3 $\mathit{lFP}1$

M4 $\mathit{\ell FP}1$


\end{document}
```

Using the default Computer Modern in a range of styles in text and math produces

[image]

If you uncomment `stix2` you get

[image]

There are many other font choices available.

Comment: Thanks a lot. that was very helpful. i will try different fonts

Comment: @ismail : If you found this answer helpful, please consider upvoting and accepting it to show your consideration ;)

Comment: @ismail note that `\ell`  is a fancy l symbol that is specifically introduced to look different to 1 but it is often too different if mixed with other letters. Looking at the above I think `\mathit{lFP}1` looks quite clear in both cm and stix.